# Is it possible to include Core Data entity type in constraint?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm working with Core Data + Swift 4.2 + Xcode 10. In my data model, I have an abstract entity A which has no parent entity, entity B which has A as its parent, and C which has A as its parent.

Entity A has a timestamp field, which is therefore inherited by B and C. I would like to impose a constraint that timestamp must be unique within an entity type. That is, I want all B items to have unique timestamps, and all C items to have unique timestamps, but some B item might have the same timestamp as some C item.

Is there a way to express that constraint in Xcode? The "Constraints" field in the entity editor wants a list of attributes. Timestamp is an attribute, so that's OK, but the entity type (B or C) is not. So I don't see a way to include entity type.

Is it possible that entity type is an implicit attribute? Just a shot in the dark here.

EDIT: To be clear, the reason I'm asking is that I tried to save an instance of B with timestamp T1 and an instance of C with timestamp T1 also, and I got an error to the effect that the constraint was violated. I was hoping that both instances would be saved (perhaps that was wishful thinking on my part). I am working with the Sqlite backend if that makes a difference.

Comment: Without knowing specifically what your code looks like, I can only speak in "physics for poets" terms. That said, you may consider creating a method wherever your entities are created to test for "uniqueness" before creating your entity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am hoping to assign the same timestamp to both objects, since they are created at the same time. I am working around the limitation by making one timestamp slightly different than the other, but that is unsatisfying; I would rather directly express the notion that the effective constraint is on the combination (entity type, constraint).

Comment: Apple makes this warning when using Sqlite: "Be careful with entity inheritance when working with SQLite persistent stores. All entities that inherit from another entity exist within the same table in SQLite. "

Comment: Understood, however, I don't think one can conclude that it's therefore impossible. In fact, I see that Core Data has constructed the table corresponding to A with a field Z_ENT which varies according to subentity. On the face of it, it seems a straightforward implementation of the desired goal would be to include Z_ENT in the constraint declared for the table.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can specify this behavior automatically in Core Data. But you can achieve this by adding another property to Entity A, and then making a constraint on the combination of that property and timestamp.

In this example, I added `subtype` to Entity A, and specified a constraint of `subtype,timestamp`.

[image]

These are the entity classes:

```
class EntityA: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var timestamp: String
    @NSManaged var subtype: String
}
class EntityB: EntityA { }
class EntityC: EntityA { }
```

You need to set the `subtype` correctly before saving the entity:

```
entity.subtype = "B"
```

or

```
entity.subtype = "C"
```

or more generically:

```
entity.subtype = entity.entity.name!
```

It's not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it would be neater if Core Data would expose an automatically-generated subtype attribute, but I can see that this does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do something similar. I ended up being able to do a switch statement with the property, and then use `case is Entity:`

```
switch variableEntity {
        case is EntityA:
            print("EntityA:")
        default:
            print("Default:")
        }
```